# RTMP live viewer alternatives to Video.js

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js, rtmp

I have a local RTMP stream that I am trying to visualize in a local webapp. A quick google search shows that Video.js is the go-to viewer. However, I can not find a working example. Scouring this site shows that it is unlikely that Video.js still supports RTMP streams.

So, if that's the case, what other modern frontend tools can I use to view a RTMP stream in my webapp? FWIW, I have an Angular 1 SPA.

Answer (score 2):

“Modern support for RTMP” doesn’t exist. RTMP requires flash, and flash will be end of life in 2020.